# Do any scriptures besides the Atharva Veda mention anything about Bhang or marijuana?

Tags: vedas, puranas

Do any of the scriptures mention anything about Bhang or marijuana.

I am aware of the atharva veda reference.

This is not a possible duplicate of "are drugs allowed question".

I just want to know if the herb was mentioned in any of scriptures

Comment: I don't think they are duplicates. This wants to know if they are mentioned. The link wants to know if they are sanctioned.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I disagree for reasons mentioned in chat; if there is a verse mentioning hemp rope being used or marijuana growing wildly in some region, then this reference is not about whether or not consumption is condoned or not. Perhaps we should ask OP to clarify his intent.

Comment: I agree with Rubellite.

Comment: You should be clear what you are asking @Kumar. Some one had to intervene to explain what you mean in the question which is not good. Cannabis and scriptures is not explaining your question properly.

Comment: Okay sarvabhouma, I will keep that in mind. Have you got the answer?

Comment: Does anybody have the answer?

Comment: Bhang is called vijayaa its memtioned in some texts. Maybe you can wait if someone posts it

Comment: I don't want all of them, Only a few will be good :)